# HTML body tag added by Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with Internet Explorer and HTML code. With Chrome, Edge and firefox all work fine, but in Explorer I have this
[image]

instead of

[image]

In debug mode I see some error into html code only with explorer:

[image]

-Translate: 
It has been found  tag in excess. In a document is allowed only one body tag.

element or end not expected. All the elements opened have to be closed before the second document end.

Token not expected

The body tag is added by browser. All other page works fine. Do you see something wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<!-- Spring csrf  -->
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Fleets &amp; cars</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport">

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link th:href="@{/static/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css}"
    rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/component/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css}">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css}">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css}">
<!-- Select2 angular -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/static/assets/plugins/select2Angular/select.css}">
<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script th:src="@{/static/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js}"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap-growl -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/notify/jquery.bootstrap-growl.js}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/dist/js/app.min.js}"></script>
<!-- Angularjs -->
<script th:src="@{/static/assets/js/angular.min.js}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Select2 angular -->
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/select2Angular/select.js}"></script>
<!-- Waiting modal -->
<script
    th:src="@{/static/assets/plugins/waiting-modal/waiting-modal.js}"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/static/assets/js/fleetAndCar.js}"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="hidden" id="role"
        th:value="${#authentication.getAuthorities()}">
    <div class="wrapper" data-ng-controller="createFleetController"
        id="createFleetControllerId">
        <!-- Header nd menu fragment -->
        <div th:replace="../fragments/dashboard-header :: dashboard-header"></div>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>Fleets Management</h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Fleets management</li>
                </ol>
            </section>
            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">

                                <h3 class="box-title">Fleets</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <!--  Fleets table -->
                                <table id="fleetsTable"
                                    class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Application</th>
                                            <th>Cubic</th>
                                            <th>Power</th>
                                            <th>Euro class</th>
                                            <th>Engine Type</th>
                                            <th>Traction</th>
                                            <th>Transmission</th>
                                            <th>Managed by</th>
                                            <th>Cars</th>
                                            <th>Add User</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                                <!-- Create two equals button because when I am on desktop I show the text add fleet otherwise the + and the tooltip. 
                                This is need because otherwise the text goes out the button -->
                                <button id="addFleetButton" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary visible-lg col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-11"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFleetModal">Add
                                    fleet</button>
                                <button id="addFleetButton" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary hidden-lg col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFleetModal">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        title="Add fleet"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- Modal to add car -->
        <div class="modal" id="addFleetModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Fleet parameters</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- form start -->
                        <form novalidate class="simple-form" name="newFleetForm">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Application</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.application" id="application"
                                        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Application"
                                        name="application" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Cubic</label> <input id="cubic"
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.cubic" type="text"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Cubic" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Power</label> <input data-ng-model="newFleet.power"
                                        id="power" type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Power" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Euro class</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.euroClass" id="euroClass" type="text"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Euro Class" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Engine type</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.engineType" id="engineType"
                                        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Engine type"
                                        required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Traction</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.traction" id="traction" type="text"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Traction" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Transmission</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.transmission" id="transmission"
                                        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Transmission"
                                        required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Note </label>(optional)
                                    <textarea data-ng-model="newFleet.note" class="form-control"
                                        rows="3" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" id=existingEcu>
                                    <label>Ecu</label>
                                    <ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
                                        data-ng-model="newFleet.ecu" required> <ui-select-match
                                        placeholder="Select ecu">
                                    {{$select.selected.note}}</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
                                        repeat="ecu.idEcu as ecu in (ecuList | filter: $select.search) track by ecu.note">
                                    <span data-ng-bind="ecu.note"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button data-ng-disabled="newFleetForm.$invalid"
                            data-ng-click="createFleet(newFleet)" id="createFleetButton"
                            type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create fleet</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->

        <!-- Modal delete Fleet -->
        <div class="modal" id="deleteFleetModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete fleet</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box-body">Are you sure? The fleet will be
                            deleted permanently, you won't be able to recover it.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok"
                            data-ng-click="deleteFleet()" id="deleteFleetButton">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <!-- Modal delete User from Fleet -->
        <div class="modal" id="deleteUserFleetModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete user from fleet</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            Are you sure to remove <label data-ng-bind="user"></label>
                            management from fleet <label data-ng-bind="fleetApplication"></label>?
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok"
                            data-ng-click="deleteUserFleet(user,fleetId)"
                            id="deleteUserFleetButton">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
        <!-- Modal add User from Fleet -->
        <div class="modal" id="addUserFleetModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add user to fleet</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group" id=fleetUser>
                                <label>Select user</label>
                                <ui-select theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
                                    data-ng-model="username" required> <ui-select-match>
                                {{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
                                    repeat="username in (fleetUserList | filter: $select.search) track by username">
                                <span data-ng-bind="username"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-ok"
                            data-ng-click="addUserFleet(username)" id="addUserFleetButton">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not a valid HTML5 code, when checked at https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea it shows errors

Comment: it doesn't allow code of angular, bootstrap and thymeleaf so validator gives error

Comment: Could not see any other issue, can you translate the errors it shows in the console.

Comment: I update, but why does explorer add body tag in this page?